# Bootstrap modal didn't close while clicking outside of modal in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I used a react-bootstrap modal to show notification in React. It works fine but it didn't close when I click outside of the modal.

Modal code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import ModalBody from "react-bootstrap/ModalBody";
import ModalHeader from "react-bootstrap/ModalHeader";
import ModalFooter from "react-bootstrap/ModalFooter";
import ModalTitle from "react-bootstrap/ModalTitle";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class ForgetPassword extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            modalIsOpen:true

        }
    }
    render()
    {
        return (
            <Modal show={this.state.modalIsOpen}>
              <ModalHeader>
                <ModalTitle>Hi</ModalTitle>
              </ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>asdfasdf</ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>This is the footer</ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
          );
    }
}
  
export default ForgetPassword;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have toggle set on the Modal component. You need to add the `toggle` prop to `<Modal>`, giving it a function, which when triggered, will toggle the value of the `IsOpen` in prop.

```js
import React from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import ModalBody from "react-bootstrap/ModalBody";
import ModalHeader from "react-bootstrap/ModalHeader";
import ModalFooter from "react-bootstrap/ModalFooter";
import ModalTitle from "react-bootstrap/ModalTitle";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class ForgetPassword extends React.Component{
  state = {
    modalIsOpen: true
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modalIsOpen: !prevState.modalIsOpen
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={this.state.modalIsOpen} onHide={this.toggleModal}>
        <ModalHeader>
          <ModalTitle>Hi</ModalTitle>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>asdfasdf</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>This is the footer</ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ForgetPassword;
```

[Source](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1487)

Comment: thanks for the help. I update my code but it didn't work. It shows 'Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onHide is not a function'

Comment: Can you paste your current code in a github https://gist.github.com/new ? I will debug the issue faster to understand why you get the TypeError.

Comment: Please see my latest update and tell me if that works. I changed it from toggle to `onHide`

Comment: Here is the link https://gist.github.com/pranaysharma995/8070a84bb9126e1f1d9cc40590dc25de

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap react docs make reference to the onHide prop that should be on the modal - A callback fired when the header closeButton or non-static backdrop is clicked. Required if either are specified.

You will want to use this to set the show modal state as false, probably through a function.